# Relationship between Users, Settings, Setting_types Eloquent Laravel 5.4*

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

How would you go to create a relationship between the folowing tables:

Users table:

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('firstname');
        $table->string('surename');
        $table->string('address')->nullable();
        $table->string('city')->nullable();
        $table->string('country')->nullable();
        $table->string('postcode')->nullable();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Setting_type table:

```
    Schema::create('setting_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Settings table:

```
    Schema::create('settings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('value');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Setting_type_user table:

```
    Schema::create('setting_type_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('type_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('setting_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('type_id')->references('id')->on('setting_types');
         $table->foreign('setting_id')->references('id')->on('settings');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

This is the result I want to get:

```
{"id":1,"value":"578943205.jpg","created_at":"2017-07-18 00:00:00","updated_at":null,"pivot":{"setting_id":1,"user_id":1,"type_id":1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on many things, but it looks like you want to use [many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship here.

First, in `settings` pibot table change it to:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
$table->unsignedInteger('type_id');
```

It's also a good idea to add [foreign key constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) to the table:

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
$table->foreign('type_id')->references('id')->on('setting_types');
```

Then define [`belongsToMany()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship in both `User` and `SettingType` models. Since you don't follow naming conventions, you have to define foreign keys manually. In the `User` model:

```
public function settingTypes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\SettingType', 'settings', 'user_id', 'type_id');
}
```

And in the `SettingType` model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'settings', 'type_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'settings' (SQL: select `settings`.*, `settings`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `settings`.`id` as `pivot_id` from `settings` inner join `settings` on `settings`.`id` = `settings`.`id` where `settings`.`user_id` is null and `id` = 1 limit 1)

Comment: @Marco if you want to help with this issue, you should post the code you're executing when getting the error.

Comment: I have done everything just like the example posted by you. For testing purposes I have created a method setting:   public function setting(){ $user = Auth::user(); return $user->settingTypes()->where('id',1)->first();}

Comment: For some reason `Auth::user()` is `null`. I guess you should start from solving this issue. For testing, you could use this instead `$user = User::find(1);`

Comment: I do get the user object with Auth::user() . You can see from the Query that is completely wrong. There must be something wrong in the relationship.